# Migrate sharepoint contents without changing ID orders

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, migration, content-migration

How to transfer sharepoint lists, contents between all versions of sharepoint without changing ID orders ?

I tried sharegate, avepoint, dell migration suite for sharepoint etc. but they couldnt work. I just preserved ID in another custom columns with these tools.

So any ideas would we welcome,

Best Regards,
Emre

Answer (score 1):

[Metalogix](http://www.metalogix.com/) Content Matrix can [preserve Item Ids](http://www.metalogix.com/help/Content%20Matrix%20Console/SharePoint%20Edition/004_FAQ/032_IdPreservationCSOM.htm).  They have a [free trial](http://www.metalogix.com/product-trials) so you can make sure it fits your needs.